# Why does window.innerHeight return 180 when in horizontal orientation?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

The viewport of iPhone 5s is 320x568. When in vertical orientation, `window.innerHeight` returns 460, which is equal to the `screen.height` - the chrome. However, when in horizontal orientation, `window.innerHeight` returns 180. There is no chrome. To my mind it should be returning 320.

This is with the viewport width set to 320.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320">
```

How is the `window.innerHeight` size derived in the horizontal (landscape) orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the viewport on mobile safari is determined by the width defined in the viewport, divided by the width of the screen (in points, not pixels) times the height of your screen (again, points not pixels) minus the size of the menubar. On the iPhone that would work like this:

`320 / 480 * 320 - 40`, which is about 180 pixels in landscape (where the points are then 480 wide and 320 height). This is the height reported, since its the height (in pixels, not points) of your *viewport*.

The reason I do (320 / 480) is to get a value that tells me how much smaller your viewport is defined than the actual screen width. Then we can use that to decrease the height (which we know in points) by the same amount, resulting in height-by-aspect-ratio from which we can subtract the size of iPhone UI elements. I am not sure about that 40, but its in that range.

### In Short

The general rule is as follows:

`(viewport.width / screen.width) * screen.height`

So in portrait, assuming your iPhone has a screen of 320x568 *points*, that would mean `320 / 320 * 568`, or `1 * 568`, so the height is reported as `568`. In landscape that would be `(320 / 568) * 320` or `0.56338028169014 * 320`, or `180.2816901408448`.

Comment: This doesn't add up. `(320/screen.width)*screen.height` 568 (OK, this is our viewport height). Then assuming that we are in a landscape view: `(568/screen.height)*screen.width` it gives 320. Which is what I am expecting, not 180.

Comment: For your landscape it is `(320/568) * 320`which is 180. You need to get the scale factor first, you need to shrink 568 by (320/568) and then shrink your height appropriately. Don't forgot that your screen height has changed when you go landscape, so `(viewportWidth / screen.width) * screen.height`should work every time. In portrait it would be `(320/320) * 568` which is `1 * 568`. In landscape it would be `320/568 * 320`.

Answer (score 0):

In the meta tag, there are certain options which could possibly make this behave the way you expect:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

No guarantee this is cross browser compatible, so you should check that out.

Comment: I should have tried setting the `maximum-scale=1.0`. I have assumed while testing that `initial-scale=1.0` is sufficient. It appears that this is the case. The scale changes as you rotate the screen.

Comment: Its actually a lot safer to use `width=device-width` as using the viewport width definition will mess with any `fixed` elements of the page, though.